# what's the difference between uppercase and lowercase printf()

Tags: c, contiki

What is the difference between uppercase and lowercase `printf()` function in C? I'm using **contiki** OS and in some files uppercase `printf` doesn't work but lowercase does.

```
if (addr == NULL) {
    uip_create_linklocal_rplnodes_mcast(&tmpaddr);
    addr = &tmpaddr;
    printf("RPL: Sending a DIS to\n ");
    PRINT6ADDR(addr);
    PRINTF("\n");
    uip_icmp6_send(addr, ICMP6_RPL, RPL_CODE_DIS, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The uppercase `PRINTF` ad `PRINT6ADDR` are probably macros defined in one of the project headers for debugging output. Look for the definition with a search tool such as **grep** or with your IDE.

A simple search on an Internet search engine finds these matches:

- http://contiki.sourceforge.net/docs/2.6/a00417_source.html
- https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/core/net/ipv6/uip-icmp6.c